# "Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource" when booting up the app

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, jhipster

This is a bit annoying since I've solved the original problem (which was this) but now this is another thing that I can't quite debug myself.

I am using JHispter 6.10 (Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE) + React for my project. I've recently come to the need of using entities as catalogues (so they can be managed easily by an admin) and they need to be used on the register page. My first problem was that they wouldn't the dropdown in the register page, but that problem had to do with `SecurityConfiguration.java`, so I added the entities to be permitted to All:

```
.antMatchers("/api/comunidad-famdals").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/ciudads").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/estados").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/ladrillo-famdals").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/pais").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

And that seems to work just fine, but the first time I load the app (in dev mode), it throws the next error:

```
2020-10-09 02:03:33.337 DEBUG 63312 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] c.f.m.r.CustomAuditEventRepository       : Enter: add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=2020-10-09T07:03:33.302498Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2020-10-09 02:03:33.342 DEBUG 63312 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] c.f.m.r.CustomAuditEventRepository       : Exit: add() with result = null
2020-10-09 02:03:33.473  WARN 63312 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
2020-10-09 02:03:33.564  WARN 63312 --- [  XNIO-1 task-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource]
```

And when trying to register, the dropdown still doesn't show anything:

[image: Dropdown empty]

But if I go home once again, the terminal shows that all the queries have been done correctly, and sure enough, if I go back to the register page:

[image: Dropdown now works]

I would like to know if I am missing something on my `SecurityConfiguration.java` or if the order of the configuration needs to be different for it to work properly.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, reading other posts seems common with jhipster. Have you solved it?

Comment: @funder7 I am no longer involved in this project I was working on but I couldn't solve it. Sorry!

Comment: If my memory works well, in the it was due to a space in the request Url, not being matched by spring security :-)

Answer (score 1):

you have to give permissions to your endpoint in the Spring Boot Configuration (SecurityConfiguration.java)

add a new `antMatchers` parameter to the `HttpSecurity.authorizeRequests()` it should look like this:

```java
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/api/yourEndpoint").permitAll()
```

of course you have to select who has authority to call this endpoint

Hope it works for you :)